# Django piston, Django.auth, and asihttprequest

Tags: iphone, django, asihttprequest, django-piston

I have a website that uses Django piston for the API. I have also created an iPhone app that successfully connects to the API and parses the JSON and displays the correct content on the iPhone. The API resource URLs are as follows

http:/mysite.com/api/pics

http:/mysite.com/api/pics/username

I'm currently hard coding the username into the above URL from within the iPhone app and there is no authentication at all. I would like these URLs to require the user to be authenticated.

My website allows logging in via the /accounts/login provided by Django. However, the code redirects the users to their profile on the website, so I'm assuming I can't just use this URL in an asihttprequest from the iPhone.

So, if I want to log a user in, using the Django's built in authentication system, what URL should I be pointing them to.  Also, once the user is authenticated I know that I'm supposed to use "is authenticated" and "challenge" for any "protected resource" in piston.  I've seen code snippets that define these functions but I'm not sure where and how to implement them. I'm used to using a decorator that just says @login_required.

Answer (score 0):

if you followed the instructions at: http://yml-blog.blogspot.com/2009/10/django-piston-authentication-against.html then looking at the example applications urls.py file https://bitbucket.org/yml/django-piston/src/dfb826a31ca8/examples/blogserver/api/urls.py you will see that authentication is passed to the resource handler.

If you've done this there is no need to use a decorator :)